# Check to see if variable is empty or not

Tags: php

So, I have an input as below:

```
<input type="text" id="rhc_phone" name="rhc_phone" placeholder="Phone number"/>
```

Which in return store as a variable:

```
var data = {

    'phone': $('#rhc_phone').val()

         };
```

This then can be extracted via following:

```
 <?php
  echo '
    <p>Call me at ' . $_POST['phone'] . '.</p>              
     ';
 ?>
```

However, the input can be left out.

Now, what is the if statement to check if the variable has `value` and if not, then show something else like below.

```
 <?php
    if (!isset($_POST['phone']) = 0) {
        echo '
       <p>Call me at ' . $_POST['phone'] . '.</p>               
        ';
    }else{
       <p>No Number</p> 
    }
 ?>
```

Is it correct?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use empty

```
if(!empty($_POST['phone'])
{ 
   echo '<p>Call me at'. $_POST['phone'] . '</p>'; 
} else {
   echo '<p>No Number</p>';
}
```

Comment: yeah, I tried and there is about 5 min required time before I can accept it :P I will do it as soon as it is available to do so. =)

Answer (score 1):

you can use `empty()` function.

[php `empty()` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)

```
if(empty($_POST['phone']))
{
    echo '<p>Number is empty</p>';
}
else
{
    echo '<p>Your Number is '.$_POST['phone'].'</p>';

}
```